# Didn't find class "com.***.***.Activity.IntroActivity" for android 4

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

My project works for Android 5 and above. But unfortunately gives the following error for android 4. How to fix the problem?

Android 4 Device information: **Samsung Galaxy Note 3 - Android 4.4.4 
 API 19**

Working Device : **Galaxy S7 7.1.0 API 25**

Android Studio  Version :  **2.3.1**

**Here is my error :**

```
   11-13 08:03:15.274 1572-1572/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.***.***, PID: 1572
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.***.***/com.***.***.Activity.IntroActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.***.***.Activity.IntroActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.***.***-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.***.***-1, /system/lib]]
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.***.***.Activity.IntroActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.***.***-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.***.***-1, /system/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Here is my Manifest.xml :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.***.***">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature    android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
 <application
     android:allowBackup="true"

     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value= "@string/facebook_app_id" />

     <provider
         android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
         android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
         android:exported="false"
         android:grantUriPermissions="true">
         <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
             android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
     </provider>

     <activity
         android:name=".Activity.IntroActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity
         android:name="com.***.***.Activity.LoginActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>

     <activity
         android:name="com.***.***.Activity.MainActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
         android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"

         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity
         android:name="com.***.***.Activity.ChangePasswordActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
     <activity
         android:name="com.***.***.Activity.MyProfileActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
     <activity
         android:name="com.***.***.Activity.RegisterActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:label="@string/register"
         />
     <activity
         android:name="com.***.***.Activity.ForgotPasswordActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
     <activity
         android:name="com.***.***.Activity.QrCodeWebViewActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
     <activity android:name="com.***.***.Activity.MyAddressActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
     <activity android:name="com.***.***.Activity.MyMessagesActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
     <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
     <service
         android:name="com.***.***.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
         </intent-filter>
     </service>
     <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
     <!-- [START of] -->
     <service
         android:name="com.***.***.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
         </intent-filter>
     </service>
     <!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->
 </application>
```

Build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.***.***"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1356
        versionName "1.2.56"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //Firebase Meesaging library


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.24.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    compile 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.0'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev134-1.22.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name and group
    }


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Are you using Multidex?

Comment: @lalongooo yes.. multiDexEnabled true

Comment: Did you trying to set full path to activity instead of `.Activity.IntroActivity` ?

Comment: @StanislavBondar Yes I tried, But nothing changed.

Comment: Also rename your package to activity (without upper case) this is a package name not a namespace

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Renamed "Activity" package to "activity" with Refactor. Then cleaned project and rebuild. But  the problem continues.